# How can I convert this large Javascript associative array into another form efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I'm working on a data processing application, which after parsing through data, the data is organized as such in an associative array:

```
sensorNumber, timeOfReading, Count, Value
2, 32242424, 2442, 42425.545545
...
4, 4343435, 2442, 42425.545545
...
```

Its a pretty straightforward 4 column data structure, however it can get pretty large - up to 1 million rows in some extreme cases.

Now, I would like to add all these data points in a chart that allows a zooming feature (which means no skipping points).

The chart needs to separate each "sensorNumber" column data in separate series, in addition to that, it needs to further separate each "count" and "value" in additional sub-series.

The most efficient chart data insertion method uses a data structure like the following:

```
time, Series1, Series2, Series3...
```

Basically all the "Y" values need to be added for each "X" value, this makes for faster insertion than plotting each X and Y at a time.

Which means I need my data structure look like the following:

**timeOfReading, Count(sensor#1), Value(sensor#1) ... Count(sensor#3),Value(sensor#3)...**

Solution#1:

1) sort all the rows by the "timeOfReading" attribute
2) create a new data structure and add columns for each "Count" and "Value" per sensor attribute to fill the row

Solution#2:

Use a dictionary, that stores arrays. Make each unique "timeOfReading" attribute a key, and create a multi-column array for each "count" and "sensor"

Solution#2 seems a LOT more efficient since it does not need any sorting whatsoever.

However, I'm wondering if there is an even more elegant solution to this that anybody could think of?

Comment: Considering numbers are not [stored precisely](http://greweb.me/2013/01/be-careful-with-js-numbers/) I wouldn't use the time of reading as a key in a map. Could this data be sorted before the JS script receives it?

Comment: To me it sounds like solution #2 maybe nicer at start but will take more code + add complexity as solution #1 is straight forward and easier to perform. It's up to you but I think #1 is preferred.

Comment: @Jacque fascinating - I cannot believe I never even heard of that. The data could be sorted differently, but that would mean altering many other parts of the program - if there is no efficient solution it will likely come down to that.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil: not sure what you mean by "not stored precisely". Every number stored is very much precise. Of course there are numbers that cannot be represented by computers, and there are numbers that cannot be represented exactly as a double. However, since timestamps are typically stored as (32 bit) ints, there is no problem in JS with that (whose double-precision number format can store integers up to 52 bits exactly).

Comment: @ Bergi I think he meant should my seconds be extremely large numbers I should watch out for this. my seconds value are well below that threshold so its fine. from the article: "9007199254740993 (which is 2^53 1) is the smallest not representable integer in Javascript. In other words, you can trust Javascript numbers before this integer!"

Comment: Sorry for offtop, but skipping points is not a good option by my opinion. it's better to show average, min and max. [For example](http://en.community.dell.com/resized-image/__size/550x0/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-02-99/ChartPortletWithEnvelope.png)